# How to create session state for one user in other browsers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one user which use one page in two browsers.

I use session for storage some object.

I should get this object in two browsers.

But CurrentSession is created in different key. How can I create the session for different browser for one user and store using the SQL Server SessionState mechanism?

Comment: Generate "CurrentSession" to be user specific, instead of browser specific?

Comment: Yes. but I need store it in a database like sqlserver session state mode

Comment: You can still do that. What's the issue?

Comment: What can I? I need store session in sqlserver mode but create only one session for one user.

Comment: You'll have to write a custom SessionState manager. You can use the existing flags to store session state in the database, but you'll need to override / implement your own StateProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the global cache object to hold user items instead of Session. With a sliding expiration equal to the `Session.Timeout` duration, it should act similar to Session.

```
    public void AddToCrossBrowserSession(string username, string key, object value)
    {
        string cacheKey = string.Format("Cross-browser-state:{0}/{1}", username, key);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(cacheKey, value, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Session.Timeout), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
    }

    public object GetFromCrossBrowserSession(string username, string key)
    {
        string cacheKey = string.Format("Cross-browser-state:{0}/{1}", username, key);
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];
    }
```

Comment: How it store in database? because it is important for me.